# javascript inheritance function causing jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance

I made 2 functions that i want to use when creating javascript "class" inheritance. I think its the first one thats causing some javascript errors, like `$ is not defined` for example. I think its just some errors that are stopping my custom jquery functions from running, thus complaining about the `$`

```
Object.prototype.Inherits = function (parent) {
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
        parent.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    }
    else {
        parent.call(this);
    }
}

Function.prototype.Inherits = function (parent) {
    this.prototype = new parent();
    this.prototype.constructor = this;
}
```

I think the first function needs a remake. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: did you import jquery lib ? and also i guess new parent() should be new Parent()? am i right ?

Comment: yes im icluding it, and it this cause it should be "parent" since its not a capital letter in the argument for the function. I think its the other function thats the problem though

Comment: what is arguments? did you define it ? where is it? you should share more code i think.

Comment: "what is arguments"? The argument for the function. You pass a parent as an argument and use it in the function.

Comment: if (arguments.length > 1) in that line. where did you define arguments ? is it same with parent ?

Comment: @erimerturk "arguments" exists by default. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments for example

Comment: Afaik jQuery is very sensible regarding prototype extensions of built-in objects. You should not do this.

Comment: @FelixKling I don't know of any issues jQuery has with adding properties to native objects, as long as it doesn't clash with stuff that already exists. I've seen a lot of code that did that, which worked perfectly well.

Comment: @Johan 1. Those errors seems to be completely unrelated to that code and 2. what are you expecting that first functions to do? it doesn't make no sense to me.

Comment: @shesek: No, jQuery does not add anything, but it expects that other code does not do it either. For example you will see `for...in` loops in the jQuery  source which do not make the `hasOwnProperty` check. Adding methods to `Object.prototype` will break that code.

Comment: @FelixKling After looking a little closer - you're right - changing `Object.prototype` can screw things up with jQuery as it does (oddly, IMHO) lack hasOwnProperty checks in several places. One example is `$.isEmptyObject` which'll always return false, which could screw up other things too. However, in code that properly uses `hasOwnProperty` or the ES6's enumrable attribute this shouldn't cause any problems. That being said, I do think that `Object.prototype` should be left unchanged (and I never touch it myself), as objects are used for dictionaries and it could create a lot confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't modify the built-in prototypes. That's not the way. Either:

- embrace the prototypal inheritance model and `Object.create()`,
- use a non-invasive solution for your methods.

Comment: That's not always true. I don't think libraries should modify native objects, but I do think a developer can and should have the freedom to do that, to make his programming environment the most productive and customized to his needs.

Comment: Insisting to use `someBuiltin.foo` instead of `foo(someBuiltin)` isn't really customisation. And (as the OP has discovered) it leads to problems.

Comment: First of all, I don't believe it caused his problems as all. His error and this code are completely unrelated, IMO. Secondly, adding methods on natives is not just "insisting to use bar.foo instead of foo(bar)" - its all about being able to make a fluent syntax for your code, i.e. `someArray.filter(...).pluck('somekey').slice(0,5).average()` rather than `average(pluck(someArray.filter(...), 'somekey').slice(0,5))`, which is MUCH less readable and makes it very hard to understand the sequence of operation takes on that data.

Comment: Yeah - but with a longer prototype chain, leading to slower code. In the array example, if you use those methods commonly, there's no benefit in extending Array with another object and than use that instead everywhere. Also, than you can't use literal arrays anymore. And again - there's NOTHING wrong with the _developer_ adding properties to native objects. IMO, libraries shouldn't be doing that, for the same reason they shouldn't be using global variables. When the developer adds his own stuff, or mix-n-match whatever suits him, it doesn't have any downside at all.

Comment: A solution without prototyping chain would be to do as in non-dynamic programming languages: `arrayAdapter(someArray).filter(...).pluck('somekey')...`

Comment: I won't disagree which your point of view, yet the practical point of view implies that the libraries tend to do what they shouldn't - and this alone is a good enough reason to avoid messing with builtins objects IMO.